# Добрый день, помогите найти ошибку пожалуйста в си

Tags: c, visual-studio

Пишу программку на си в Visual Studio 2008, которая с помощью стека ищет правильность расстановки скобок в строке {}, (), [].
И вылезает куча ошибок:

```
Ошибка  1   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед "*"    d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 16  Skobki1
Ошибка  2   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие "{" перед "*"    d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 16  Skobki1
Ошибка  3   error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: )   d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 16  Skobki1
Ошибка  4   error C2054: требуется "(" после "p"    d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 17  Skobki1
Ошибка  5   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед "*"    d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 24  Skobki1
Ошибка  6   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие "{" перед "*"    d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 24  Skobki1
Ошибка  7   error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: тип d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 24  Skobki1
Ошибка  8   error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: )   d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 24  Skobki1
Ошибка  9   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед "*"    d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 30  Skobki1
Ошибка  10  error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие "{" перед "*"    d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 30  Skobki1
Ошибка  11  error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: )   d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 30  Skobki1
Ошибка  12  error C2054: требуется "(" после "p"    d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 31  Skobki1
Ошибка  13  error C2065: Stack: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 42  Skobki1
Ошибка  14  error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "stek1"    d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 42  Skobki1
Ошибка  15  error C2065: stek1: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 42  Skobki1
Ошибка  16  error C2065: stek2: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 42  Skobki1
Ошибка  17  error C2065: stek3: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 42  Skobki1
Ошибка  18  error C2065: stek1: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 43  Skobki1
Ошибка  19  error C2223: выражение слева от "->count" должно указывать на структуру или объединение d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 43  Skobki1
Ошибка  20  error C2065: stek2: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 44  Skobki1
Ошибка  21  error C2223: выражение слева от "->count" должно указывать на структуру или объединение d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 44  Skobki1
Ошибка  22  error C2065: stek3: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 45  Skobki1
Ошибка  23  error C2223: выражение слева от "->count" должно указывать на структуру или объединение d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 45  Skobki1
Ошибка  25  error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "=="   d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 51  Skobki1
Ошибка  26  error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: )   d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 51  Skobki1
Ошибка  29  error C2065: stek2: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 55  Skobki1
Ошибка  31  error C2065: stek3: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 58  Skobki1
Ошибка  34  error C2065: stek1: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 61  Skobki1
Ошибка  36  error C2065: stek2: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 64  Skobki1
Ошибка  38  error C2065: stek3: необъявленный идентификатор d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 67  Skobki1
Ошибка  39  error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: return  d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 76  Skobki1
Ошибка  40  error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: }   d:\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\skobki1\main.c 77  Skobki1
```

Вот, собственно, сам код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

struct Stack
{
    int A[255];
    int count;
};


//проверка стека на пустоту
int isFull(Stack *p)
{
    if (p -> count ==0 ) return 1;
    else if ( p->count == n) return -1;
    else return 0;
}


void pushIntoStek(Stack *p, char elem)  // включение в стек
{
    p -> A[p -> count] = elem;
    p -> count++;
}

int  deleteFromStek(Stack *p)             // удаление из стека
{
    if (isFull(p)==1) 
    {
        p -> count--;
        return 0;
    }
    else return -1;
}
int parser (char* str, int* numOfChar)
{
    int numChar, i;
    Stack stek1, stek2, stek3;           
    stek1-> count = 0;
    stek2-> count = 0;
    stek3-> count = 0;


    for (i = 0; i<255; i++){
        numChar = 0;
        if (str[i] == "") break;
        if (str[i]) == "{"){
            pushIntoStek(&stek1, str[i]);// pushIntoStek заносит символ скобки в стек
        }
        if (str[i] == "("){
            pushIntoStek(&stek2, str[i]);// pushIntoStek заносит символ скобки в стек
        }
        if (str[i] == "["){
              pushIntoStek(&stek3, str[i]);// pushIntoStek заносит символ скобки в стек
        }
        if (str[i] == "}") {
            numChar = deleteFromStek(&stek1);//deleteFromStek удаляет элемент из стека и  возвращает 0 при успешной попытке или -1 при неуспешной(стек пуст)
        } 
        if (str[i] == ")"){    
            numChar = deleteFromStek(&stek2);//deleteFromStek удаляет элемент из стека и  возвращает 0 при успешной попытке или -1 при неуспешной(стек пуст)
        }    
        if (str[i] == "]"){
            numChar = deleteFromStek(&stek3);//deleteFromStek удаляет элемент из стека и  возвращает 0 при успешной попытке или -1 при неуспешной(стек пуст)
        }
        if (numChar != 0) {
            numOfChar[i] = numChar;   
        }

    } 


    return 0;
}

void main(){
       // SetConsoleCP(1251);
       // SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        //setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" ); 
        //system("cls");

        char str[255];  
        int i, numOfChar[255];

        for (i = 0; i<255; i++){
            str[i] = "";
        }         

        for (i = 0; i<255; i++){
            numOfChar[i] = 0;
        }  
        printf("Input a string including (), {}, [] \n");
        gets(str);   
        printf ("%s ",&str);
        getch();

        parser(&str, &numOfChar);

        if (numOfChar[0] == 0) printf("Errors haven't found");
        else { 
            printf("Error have found in numplaces: ");
            for (i = 0; i<255; i++){
                printf("d ", numOfChar[i]);
            }      
        }

}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в чем тут дело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. У вас опечатка на этой строке:

   ```
   // -------v
   if (str[i]) == "{"){
   ```
2. Вы неверно производите сравнение символа по индексу:

   ```
   if (str[i] == "{")
   ```

   должно быть:

   ```
   if (str[i] == '{')
   ```
3. Поскольку вы не использовали `typedef`, при декларировании структуры нужно везде писать `struct Stack` вместо `Stack`, т.е.:

   ```
   int isFull(struct Stack *p)
   ```

Для проверки кода всегда читайте что вам говорит лог ошибок: он четко указывает файл и строку, где находится проблема.

Comment: 1. Исправила 2.Спасибо, что подсказали. Однако первая ошибка, на которую Visual studio ругается, это строка int isFull(Stack *p)

Comment: @еленабырканова Поскольку вы не использовали `typedef` при декларировании структуры, нужно везде писать `struct Stack` вместо `Stack`.

Comment: @еленабырканова Не за что. Не забывайте, что компилятор всегда подскажет вам, где находится синтаксическая ошибка. Сложнее с логическими ошибками, приводящими к проблемам с памятью (segmentation fault, stack overflow и т.д.), но для этого существует отладчик (debugger).